# How to read blob from url using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an existing code that uses `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` library to upload the blob in Azure Storage and provide a SAS url to the client. But, we have to change that to read the content of the blob using C# code to do further processing.

I have seen various code to download the file using fileName but none with url. Can someone point me to the code that can read the blob from a url?

This is the code that we use to upload the data.

```
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = _blobStorageHelper.CreateCloudBlobContainer(Id);
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = _blobStorageHelper.CreateCloudBlockBlob(cloudBlobContainer, localFileName);
cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "application/fhir+ndjson";
cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(localFileName);
```

Now, to download I see that `CloudBlockBlob` has a method `DownloadText()` but not sure how can I use it or any other method to read the content from a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CloudBlockBlob(Uri)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#microsoft-azure-storage-blob-cloudblockblob-ctor(system-uri)) constructor to create an instance of `CloudBlockBlob` using a SAS URL. The `Uri` parameter is the SAS URL.

Other option would be to use [`CloudBlockBlob(Uri, StorageCredentials)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#microsoft-azure-storage-blob-cloudblockblob-ctor(system-uri-microsoft-azure-storage-auth-storagecredentials)) where the `Uri` parameter is the Blob URL and [`StorageCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.auth.storagecredentials.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#microsoft-azure-storage-auth-storagecredentials-ctor(system-string)) is constructed using SAS token.